# PostgreSQL Trigger update all row in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, updates

I want calculate a field when update one or two fields but Trigger calculate all table's row with same value, not only the row updated. What is wrong ..? Thank you.

```
Create or Replace Function hospital_ocupation() returns Trigger
as
$$
Begin

update hospital set p_ocupation = (new.n_cases*100)/new.capacity
where old.n_case <> new.n_case; 

return new;

End
$$
language plpgsql;


Create Trigger update_ocupation after update on hospital
for each row
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
execute procedure hospital_ocupation();


update hospital set capacity=500,n_cases=50
where id_hospital = 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eyJV.png)

Comment: Why don't you use the primary key in the first update?

Comment: Change your update statement as `update hospital set p_ocupation = (new.n_cases*100)/new.capacity
where old.n_case <> new.n_case and id_hospital=NEW.id_hospital;`

Comment: Perfect! It's worked, Thank very much!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use UPDATE, assign the calculated value to the new record in a BEFORE trigger:

```
create or replace function hospital_ocupation() 
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.p_ocupation := (new.n_cases*100)/new.capacity;
  return new;
End
$$
language plpgsql;
```

To make that work you need a **BEFORE** trigger:

```
create trigger update_ocupation 
BEFORE update on hospital
for each row
WHEN (old.n_case <> new.n_case) 
execute procedure hospital_ocupation();
```